# ipython notebook rearrange command history order

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working on a demo notebook. While working on it I am inserting commands and sometimes going back at a previous cell to insert more commands. At the end, I want the command numbering to be increasing order, not the random order I entered them while preparing the notebook.

Any way to conveniently do this from the notebook? I can go and edit the .ipynb file associated with the notebook and edit the "prompt_number" fields to make the command ordering as I want, but a more convenient way is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on no responses, I am posting the editing of the underlying .ipynb file as the answer to rearrange numbering.

When you edit the ipynb file, note that most of the time the numbers are paired (output and input):

```
   "output_type": "pyout",
   "prompt_number": 35,
   "text": [
    "Empty DataFrame\n",
    "Columns: [utilization]\n",
    "Index: []"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "prompt_number": 35
},
```

**vim tip**: I did a /prompt_n/b+16 search on vim which takes you to the beginning of the number, then just doing cw to the new number you want works. For the second number of the pair, just do .

**Note:** Be careful about the paired numbers, I found the first one is the output one and ends with a comma. The second one is the input one without a comma. But if you have intentionally deleted a particular in/out cell from the web interface, the pair may be missing so be careful to put same new number to same in/out pair, and not give same number to different in/out cells, which will garble the notebook and web interface will complain about errors.